# How to clone a struct which holds a trait object to a `Fn`

Tags: rust, clone, traits

I have the following struct :

```
#[derive(Clone)]
pub struct MyStruct {
  function : Box<dyn Fn(Box<dyn Any>) -> Box<dyn Any> + Send + Sync>,
  [...]
}
```

The clone derivation fails because the box isn't `Clone` but I don't have a way to make the Fn `Clone`, is there a way out of this ? The reason I need clone is that I sometimes pass around `&[MyStruct]` and need to clone to own with `.to_vec()`...

Answer (score 3):

Simple answer : switch the `Box` (a single-owner pointer) to an `Rc` or `Arc` (shareable pointers)